# Why is my React onChange event handler not firing?

Tags: reactjs

Perplexed at why my React event handler doesn't seem to be firing (console.log isn't outputting). I do have a component class for CertTypeSelect. Seems like the handler should fire. I need to type more non-code here for SO's system to allow for me to save my edits, even more non-code even more non-code even more non-code even more non-code even more non-code even more non-code even more non-code even more non-code.

```
class CertTypeSelect extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(); // super(props);
        this.state = {

        }; // this.state

    } // constructor

    render() {

        const certTypeOptions = []; // 
        certTypeOptions.push(<CertSelectOption optionText="Select type"/>); // 
        storeData.forEach((storeDatum) => {
            certTypeOptions.push(
                <CertSelectOption optionText={storeDatum.catTitle}/>
            ); // push
        }); // forEach

        return (

            <div className="form-group third"><p><strong>Type</strong></p>
            <label className="select">
                <select name="govcapost-cert-type" id="govcapost-cert-type">{certTypeOptions}</select>
            </label></div>

        ); // return

    } // render

} // CertTypeSelect

    // top-most "app" component:
    class CertSelectionControls extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {

            super(props); // 

            this.state = {

                type: 'Select type',
                level: 'Select level',
                replacement: false

            }; // this.state

            // all componenent methods must be bound during the constructor - 
            this.setType = this.setType.bind(this); //

            // log(this.state) // yes works

        } // constructor


        setType(event) {

            console.log('setType')
            // this.setState({type:event.target.value}); // setState

        } // setType

        render() {

            return (

                <span><div className="group"><CertTypeSelect value={this.state.type} onChange={this.setType} /></div><CertPricePreview /><CertContinueButton /></span>

            ); // return

        } // render
    } // CertSelectionControls
```

Comment: can you provide the code for CertTypeSelect?

Comment: Please share the code of CertTypeSelect component because you are passing setType to CertTypeSelect as onChange prop so in the component you should call it

Comment: You attached the event to a component and not to a jsx tag. If you want to keep that you will to trigger the event within that component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since CertTypeSelect is a custom component and not a generic jsx tag the onChange is passed as a prop to CertTypeSelect

You will need to call this onChange function inside CertTypeSelect.

Also is the onChange a valid attribute for the element inside CertTypeSelect? If not there will be no event parameter to pass to your function.